# How can I snap to line intersections in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, snapping

I have two Bezier curves and I want to snap to their intersection. Unfortunately, 'snap to path intersection' only works on actual paths; I can't use it on lines. I decided to test this out on straight lines as well but even that failed. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. How did you make the lines?

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the version of Inkscape I had with 1.0 and lines intersections appear to snap